# What happens in Redis cache with Volatile-LRU maxmemory policy when memory get filled?

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache

I have a redis cache in Azure with maxmemory policy set as Volatile-LRU. When writing to Redis, I am not adding an expiry time for the key. In this case, what will happen when the cache memory get filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the `volatile-lru` policy, redis will never evict a key without a expiry. If all of memory is used up by keys that do not have expiry set then the next time you use a command that requires allocating more memory than is available, say `SET`, the command will fail and you will get this error message:

```
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'
```

You will still be able to use commands that don't allocate memory, like `GET`. If you get your database into this state, you can use the `EXPIRE` command to set and expiry time on keys after the fact.